# How to put CJK in subscript

Tags: xetex, subscripts, cjk, xecjk

I want to put a hiragana character in subscript.
I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\setCJKmainfont{VL Gothic}

\begin{document}

V$_{\text{る}}$

\end{document}
```

but get

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.10 V$_{\text
>   {る}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\text` command requires `amsmath` (or `amstext` that's automatically  loaded by `amsmath`). However, for textual subscripts there is `\textsubscript`.

I changed the fonts to ones I have, just to show the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fix-cm} % to turn off annoying warnings

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{Heiti SC}

\begin{document}

V\textsubscript{る}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oQQqQ.png That is quite the URL. Sorry, totally irrelevant, but

Comment: @Au101 Sorry, but I don't understand

Comment: That's the URL of the png image you uploaded showing the output. The long series of qs, plus the roundedness of the o and the qs - it just struck me as a very pleasing random series of letters, the kind of URL you wouldn't get very often, since I assume they're just generated sequences of letters. But I'm just that sort of sad person who notices that kind of thing. Like when the time is 11:11:11, or when it was the 12th of December 2012 (12/12/12). *Shrug*. Anyway

Comment: @Au101 Now I see! My father says ”the little geese“ when a digital clock shows 22:22